# Cordova FileChoser plugin showing non-existing files(Document->Downloads) folder

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

We are using Cordova FileChoser plugin in our hybrid(cordova) mobile app for selecting file. When we launch the plugin and go to Documents->Downloads folder it shows non existing or already deleted files.

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Hi  we are using this plugin [https://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser](https://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser) , calling this plugin using javascript code **fileChooser.open(function(uri) {
    //success callback
}, function(){ //error callback });**